# if a finite limit $L = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) $ exists. Prove that $\exists M >0$ , $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [a, +\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

The question is given below:

Let $f$ be a continuous function for $x \geq a,$ and suppose that a finite limit $L = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) $ exists. Prove that there exists $M >0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [a, +\infty).$

**My Thoughts**

1-But I wonder how can I prove this, will I use a proof similar to the comparison test?

2- Will the proof include the use this problem:

Let $f$ be an increasing function for $x \geq a,$ and suppose that a finite limit $L = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) $ exists. Prove that $f(x) \leq L$ for all $x \in [a, +\infty).$and that $f$ is bounded on $[a, +\infty).$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of limit, we know there exist a $X\in [a,+\infty)$, such that 
$$|f(x)-L|<1,\,\,\,x>X$$ 
which implies that
$$|f(x)|<1+|L|,\,\,\,x>X$$
If $X=a$, let $M=\max{(1+|L|,|f(a)|)}$, then we've done.

If $X>a$, we know there exist $N>0$ such that
$$|f(x)|<N,\,\,x\in[a,X]$$
by the continuity of $f$ on $[a,X]$. Let $M=\max{(1+|L|,N)}$, we've done.

Comment: Could you please clarify from where your forth line come ?

Comment: $|f(x)-L|<1$ is also $-1<f(x)-L<1$ and $-1+L<f(x)<1+L$. Then $$|f(x)|<\max(|L-1|,|L+1|) \leq 1+|L|$$

Comment: is this a well known fact?

Comment: I think so .....

Comment: why if X=a we are done?

Comment: @hopefully edited

Answer (score 2):

We know that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N>0$ such that $x>N$, then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

In particular, there is an $N_1>0$, such that $x > N$, then $|f(x)-L| < 1$. then we have $|f(x) | < |L|+1$.

Let $W = \max_{x \in [a, N]} |f(x)|.$

I'm leaving the last step for you to use these to construct an upper bound for $|f(x)|$.

Remark: We can't assume that $f$ is monotonic.

Comment: Could you provide some details about this last step please?

Comment: I think $L+1$ is not necessary a positive number.

Comment: true, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @hopefully the answer has actually been provided in the other answer but the idea is that we know number that are big enough is bounded by a number $M_1$, number that are not too large is bounded by $M_2$. how do you select a common upper bound for both smaller number and big number at the same time? A simple analogy, you have two children, one spends more than the other,  say one spend $5$ dollars per day and one spend $10$ dollars per day? how do you make sure they have enough to spend each day if you want to give them the same amount to spend.

Comment: Could you please clarify from where your third line come?

Comment: third line is defining $W$ to be the maximum of $|f(x)|$ on $[a,N]$? the maximum is attained because $|f|$ iscontinuous.

Comment: this is the forth line not the third one.

Comment: uh oh, there is a possibility that you haven't understood the other solution as well. If $a \le c$ and $b \le d$, do you agree that $a \le \max(c,d)$ and $b \le \max(c,d)$?